# Set system time using Qt through DBus

Tags: qt, dbus, freedesktop.org

I try to set system time using Qt [through DBus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated/) in the following way:

```
#include <QDBusConnection>
#include <QDBusInterface>
#include <QDBusMessage>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int /*argc*/, char ** /*argv*/)
{
    QDBusConnection dbConnection = QDBusConnection::systemBus ();
    QDBusInterface dbInterface (
            "org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time"
          , "/org/freedesktop/timedate1/set-time/Manager"
          , "org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time.Manager"
          , dbConnection);
    qDebug () << "DBus interface validation: " << dbInterface.isValid ();
    if (dbInterface.isValid () ) {
        QDBusMessage dbMessage = dbInterface.call ("SetTime", QDateTime::currentDateTime ().toMSecsSinceEpoch () * 1000, false, false);
        qDebug () << "DBus message: " << dbMessage;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I've got: `DBus interface validation: false`.

If I call in the console:

```
$ gdbus introspect \
      --system \
      --dest org.freedesktop.timedate1 \
      --object-path /org/freedesktop/timedate1
```

I get some relevant output (so it looks like no problems with environment):

```
node /org/freedesktop/timedate1 {
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer {
        ...
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable {
        ...
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties {
    methods:
        ...
    signals:
        ...
    properties:
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.timedate1 {
    methods:
      SetTime(in  x arg_0,
              in  b arg_1,
              in  b arg_2);
        ...
    signals:
    properties:
        ...
  };
};
```

Source code and build script available at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/37784882).

Comment: Looks like the object needs to be instantiated. When I look with `d-feet` - it's not there. Then I launch `$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.timedate1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/timedate1` from terminal - timedate1 appears (and the Qt application then reports it as valid).

Comment: @Velkan, `Looks like the object needs to be instantiated.` I'm not familiar with D-Bus. Can you explain what exactly should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. Wrong D-Bus command is used. Before try writing Qt program I must debug the command with console. So correct command is:

   ```
   dbus-send \
       --system \
       --print-reply \
       --type=method_call \
       --dest='org.freedesktop.timedate1' \
              '/org/freedesktop/timedate1' \
               org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetTime \
                   int64:120000000 \
                   boolean:true \
                   boolean:false
   ```
2. When ntp service is used command will be performed with error: `Automatic time synchronization is enabled`. So (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683067/how-to-stop-automatic-time-update-via-terminal)) synchronization must be disabled:

   ```
   timedatectl set-ntp 0
   ```
3. As mentioned by @Velcan timedated service is in inactive state:

   > the service is started when someone tries to access the name
   >   `org.freedesktop.timedate1`

   In my environment (`KUbuntu 15.10 x86_64`) the service is in active state 30 seconds after last call.
4. According to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusabstractinterface.html#isValid):

   > **bool QDBusAbstractInterface::isValid() const**
   >
   > Returns true if this is a
   >   valid reference to a remote object. It returns false if there was an
   >   error during the creation of this interface (for instance, if the
   >   remote application does not exist).
   >
   > Note: when dealing with remote objects, **it is not always** possible to
   >   determine if it exists when creating a QDBusInterface.
5. Even if `QDBusAbstractInterface::isValid()` returns `false` the `call` function performs with successful result.
6. So finally, correct code is very short and simple:

   ```
   QDBusInterface dbInterface (
       "org.freedesktop.timedate1"
     , "/org/freedesktop/timedate1"
     , "org.freedesktop.timedate1"
     , QDBusConnection::systemBus () );
   qDebug () << dbInterface.call ("SetTime", 120000000ll, true, false);
   ```

   This command sets time to two minutes ahead.

   Thanks @Velkan for help in solving the question and providing useful information!

Answer (score 1):

In short: a retry loop on `QDBusInterface` creation does the job.

I explored a bit more. That dbus object is provided by the `systemd-timedated` service. To know its status:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-timedated
```

The config of the service is in `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timedated.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Time & Date Service
Documentation=man:systemd-timedated.service(8) man:localtime(5)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timedated
BusName=org.freedesktop.timedate1
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_TIME
WatchdogSec=1min
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectSystem=yes
ProtectHome=yes
```

The `BusName` setting is responsible for the so-called 'D-Bus activation of a service'. So, the service is started when someone tries to access the name `org.freedesktop.timedate1`.

But apparently it takes time to start. I don't know how it's supposed to be done cleanly, but you can make a retry loop that creates `QDBusInterface`. You'll see that `sudo systemctl status systemd-timedated` becomes active and Qt retrieves a valid interface.

Object name and path that I've tried:

```
QDBusInterface dbInterface (
    "org.freedesktop.timedate1"
    , "/org/freedesktop/timedate1"
    , "org.freedesktop.timedate1"
    , dbConnection);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is very useful for me! But in my opinion proposed solution isn't good enough.